# C program array print incorrect data

Tags: c, arrays

### This is my code

```
 int a;
char array[10];

printf("Enter a number \n");
scanf("%d", &a);
array[1] = a;


printf("array = %d\n",array[1]);
```

problem is if I enter a number that is more than 4 for example 12345 then it will print something else instead of 12345

some help me

Answer (score 5):

You have the array of type char. The size of a char is 1 byte and so it fits values from -128 to 127. Any bigger value will overflow. If you want to store bigger values use a different type - short, int, even long long if needed.

Answer (score 1):

why are you storing an int into a char array .. big values of `a` will overflow ..

we can help you more if you explain what you are trying to do in your code .. because I don't see any reason for you to store an `int` into a `char` array

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing a couple of things.

Firstly: arrays start at index [0] -- is there any reason to start at index 1?

Secondly, as others pointed out, an array of `char` (i.e. numbers between -128 and 127) will not store numbers outside that range.

Thirdly, what I think you want is convert the binary number `a` to a string `array`. For this you need to use `sprintf()` (in the case of C, or `itoa` in the case of C++):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
  int a;
  char array[10];
  printf("Enter a number \n");
  scanf("%d", &a);
  sprintf(array,"%d",a); 
  printf("array = %s\n",array);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few errors:

So if you want to print what you entered, try this:

```
printf("a = %d\n", a);
```

However, if you REALLY want to start putting stuff into arrays, lets talk about a few things...

First of all, arrays are 0 indexed, so instead of `array[1] = a`, you would do `array[0] = a'

Second, this is casting an `int` (which is most likely 32-bits) to a `char` (most likely 8-bits).  So the maximum amount you can have in it is `255` (Actually this can get a bit muddy... the standard doesn't specify if `char` is `signed` or `unsigned`. Therefore, the max might actually be `127`!).

If you explain what your end goal is, I can expand further.

Answer (score 0):

Um, this code seems wrong on quite a few levels.

You're scanning a number as a string, and then assigning it to an integer without using `stoi()`. So the only thing that will be the same b/w `array[1]` and the number you scan, `a` will be that their binary representation match up to some degree (upto 1 byte).

If you're scanning 10digit numbers simply use:

```
long long int a;
scanf("%10lld", &a);
```